# How to add onclick function in wordpress menu item to show page section (display: none;)

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I am trying to add a onclick function to a menu item in WordPress. I am trying with this old-school code, but it's not working.

I use the same code as before that works for me, but obviously it's not working now on this type:

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('#menu-item-1496').bind( "click", function() {
            jQuery ('#products').show();
        });
    });
</script>
```

What I want to make is, when you click on menu item(now they are just linked to sections, like Scroll to ID), to show section that is linked to. I've added CSS: display:none; but the JS code is not working.. I want it hidden section by default, and when you click on menu item to lead you to that section and appear.. Is that possible with JS?

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? `.bind()` hasn't been around for a while now. Also, what errors are you getting in the console?

Comment: I am getting this error: Uncaught SyntaxError: private fields are not currently supported. I've added this again into header, then I don't get any error message.

Comment: Actually, I don't get any error anymore. But it's not working

Comment: And your jQuery version?

Comment: I guess it's latest, because of the Wordpress update and support of the language

Comment: If it's the latest, then `.bind()` doesn't exist in it. Use `.on()` instead

Comment: Still not working, only the section is not visible